# unmet dependencies linux-server depend on linux-image-server

Tags: server, kernel, dependencies

on my **Ubuntu server 12.04.2**, LVM partition, I have this problem when I run `apt-get -f install` :

```
apt-get-f install
Reading package lists ... done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... done
Correcting dependencies ... done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer needed:
   linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-37 linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
   linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
   linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
It is necessary to o 1736 in the archives.
After this operation, 1024 o of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y / n]? o
Reception: 1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-server amd64 3.2.0.41.49 [1736 B]
1736 o approved in 0s (57.2 kB / s)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
  linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.39.47), however:
   The version of linux-image-server on the system is 3.2.0.41.49.
  linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.39.47), however:
   The version of linux-headers-server on the system is 3.2.0.41.49.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (- configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No "contribution" report was created because the error message indicates an error running a previous failure.
                           Errors were encountered while processing:
  linux-server
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to download linux-server_3.2.0.39.47_amd64.deb and `dpkg -i linux-server_3.2.0.39.47_amd64.deb` but it says kernel already installed.

Any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-server_3.2.0.41.49_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-server_3.2.0.41.49_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Seemed too easy, but fixed the same problem for me!  (different versions, but same error)  :)